# Ionic Capacitor - using Cordova plugins

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am attempting to use `@ionic-native/http` on iOS and Web with no success. App starts on both platforms, but the plugin does not work.

## Dependencies

- capacitor: "^1.0.0-beta.19"
- @ionic/angular: "^4.1.0"
- @angular: "^7.2.2"
- @ionic-native: "^5.0.0"
- @ionic/angular-toolkit: "~1.4.0"

I hope that covers the most important ones.

## Steps to reproduce

### App

1. `ionic start myApp tabs`
2. `npm install --save @capacitor/cli @capacitor/core`
3. `npm run build --prod`
4. `npx cap init <name> <id>`
5. `npx cap add ios`
6. `npx cap copy`
7. `npx cap open ios`

   - general -> signing -> team

### Plugin

1. `npm install cordova-plugin-advanced-http`
2. `npm install @ionic-native/http`
3. `npx cap sync`
4. Use it as shown in [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http#usage)

According to the [documentation](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/cordova/) (which I might have misunderstood) that should be it.

## Issues

When attempting to call an API:

### Web

`Native: tried calling HTTP.get, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator`

I know I don't use Cordova per se but shouldn't it be covered by `npx cap sync`?

### iOS

```
[error] - ERROR {"line":38,"column":38,"sourceURL":"capacitor://localhost/tab2-tab2-module.js"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was lucky to finally find some more information.

## iOS

I am not really sure why, but this additional plugin helped https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend. Requests can be made through `HttpClient` and they use Cordova plugin so that they bypass proxy.

## Web

Capacitor won't work on the browser according to https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/767#issuecomment-415481452

So my assumption that it will was wrong. Previously mentioned [plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/767#issuecomment-415481452) will delegate requests through `HttpClient` so it is nice workaround for the browser, although won't fix CORS issue.

> CORS issue at this point can be handled by a [proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server).